# PayPal API: Getting payee information from an authorisation or capture

Tags: api, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

Using PayPal's REST API, how can I retrieve payee information from a capture/authorisation?

I'm specifically looking for the payee name, but neither the [capture](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#capture-object) or [authorization](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#authorization-object) objects seem to present this data.